# How to remove toggle functionality when clicked on Inner elements

Tags: jquery

In the jsfiddle

Once clicked on Office

It displays its child elements present in **office**

I need to close and open the div if clicked on office header (Which is happening currently)

But if clicked on its (office) child elements , i dont want the toggle functionality (the inner elements should not get closed)

This is my http://jsfiddle.net/5j1tdn7h/1/

when clciked on the selection , this method will be called

```
$(document).on('click', '.lielement', function() {
    var locationname = $(this).attr("id");
    if($(this).find('.restListings').length)
        $(this).find('.restListings').remove()
        else
    displayingRestaurantByArea(locationname);
});
```

could you please let me know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Stop the click event from bubbling up the DOM and triggering the click event on the parent by adding:

```
$('#restmenu').on('click', '.restListings', function () {
    return false;
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5j1tdn7h/2/)**

Comment: You might want to use event.stopPropagation() instead of return false, though.

Comment: @j08691 It's the function designed to prevent bubbling, return false would prevent normal behavior (like clicking links).

Comment: @AndreBacklund - True, but `.restListings` isn't a link so either works fine here.